# Wordpress Mobile Menu JQuery Selector Trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, selection

I’m having trouble with a small mechanics difference between a full-view menu and a mobile-view menu (using the same ul>li>a structure). In the mobile view, the menu hides until the .showMe class is added to its parent div. No problem there, but when I try to select the submenus by using .showMe in the selector chain (in order to perform jQuery actions only when in mobile mode), the script breaks and the dependent actions never occur.

The chunk of selecting code in question is here:

```
$('.showMe .menu-item-has-children > a').click(function(event){

    // prevent default link behavior
    if (!($(this).siblings('.sub-menu').hasClass('expanded'))) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    // close down any open submenus
    $('.sub-menu').removeClass('expanded');

    // expand the clicked link’s child ul
    $(this).siblings('.sub-menu').toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

If I remove the `.showMe` selector from the top line, the effect works great.

See the live site for testing here: http://www.wwva.org.php53-14.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/students

I feel like I’m going crazy here—what am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The event handler is only added to the elements that match the selector *at the time it's bound*. Adding a class later means the event handler won't work for those elements, as they didn't match the selector when the event handler was bound.

Comment: Ahh. That’s it. This event handler is added on $(document).ready(), and the showMe class is added after that. What might be the best solution in a case like this--adding the event handler in a callback from the addition of the showMe class?

Comment: You can check for the class inside the event handler

Comment: Oh, of course! Works smoothly now.

Thanks very much for your help on this. Kind of you to help out a beginner!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in comments—thanks adeneo!

"The event handler is only added to the elements that match the selector at the time it's bound. Adding a class later means the event handler won't work for those elements, as they didn't match the selector when the event handler was bound. ... You can check for the class inside the event handler."